# apache2 server no permission on new directory

Tags: permissions, virtualhost, apache2, www-data

I am setting up an apache2 server on my server. I wanted to use another directory then /var/www. I created the directory /web

added my user to the www-data group

changed the owner/group and the permission:

```
chown -R root:www-data /web
chmod -R 755 /web
```

and then I created a new virtualhost with the right directory root enabled the site disabled the default one. Restarted the server.

But my server says: Forbidden you don't have permission....
I don't get why, I have already tried all possible tutorials of diverse forums and websites, but I can't get it working

My virtualhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /web/test

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You need to show us your configuration to help you.

Comment: Which configuration file exactly? Since I run it in Ubuntu I have multiple files

Comment: Apache config (at least show us what you have changed)!

Comment: Ubuntu has multiple files

Comment: I now have edited my post

Comment: you should use `chmod 770`

Comment: Ok thank you good to know! :) but this doesn't solve my problem

Comment: What version of Apache2 are you using? There is a difference in 2.2 vs. 2.4 regarding how access to a directory is handled/given/granted

Comment: You should use some other user than root for the owner of the directory, so that you don't need to be `root` to add files there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find your apache2.conf or the default apache configuration file depending on your linux distribution and make sure it has a directory configuration for your new web root. Something on the lines of:

```
<Directory /web/test/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! I didn't knew that I have to specify the Directory!